# Scrapy Passing Arguments and Writing to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I am working on a data scraping project and am new with scrapy. It seems powerful but is also tricky (at first, at least).

My MySQL database includes 2 tables: "thelist" and "data".

The thelist table is a list of entities - businesses, blogs, venues, etc. - for which I have scraped directory sites (using mechanize, BeautifulSoup, and regex). The row id from thelist is "thelist_id" in the data table, which is a foreign key back to thelist table.

Now I want to use a spider to go to each entity's own website and scrape for email. I plan to use a python script that selects an entity from "thelist" and uses os.system to run scrapy and send it command line arguments.

```
$ scrapy crawl furious -a domain=930.com -a start_url='http://www.930.com/' -a thelist_id=137522
```

Upon completion of scraping, scrapy should write the retrieved emails back to the database, to the data table, and it needs thelist_id value from the command line argument to write in that column's info so it relates back to thelist table (master list of entities).

Here are the various scripts:

items.py

```
import scrapy

class FuriousmeItem(scrapy.Item):
    emails = scrapy.Field()
    thelist_id = scrapy.Field()
```

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'furiousme'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['furiousme.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'furiousme.spiders'

ITEM_PIPELINES = [
    'furiousme.pipelines.FuriousmePipeline',
]
```

furious.py (the spider)

```
import scrapy
from furiousme.items import FuriousmeItem


class FuriousSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "furious"

    def __init__(self, domain, start_url, thelist_id):
        self.allowed_domains = [domain]
        self.start_urls = [start_url]
        self.thelist_id = thelist_id


    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css("a::attr('href')"):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath("//body//a"):
            item = FuriousmeItem()
            item['emails'] = response.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]/text()").extract()
            item['entity_id'] = self.thelist_id
            yield item
```

pipelines.py

```
import logging
import sys

# DATABASE
import pymysql
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.sql import table, column, exists
from sqlalchemy import *

sys.path.append("/Volumes/Orange-1a/^datamine/^scripts/^foundation/")
import music_tables
from music_tables import *

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class FuriousmePipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.seen = []

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        logger.info(item)

        some_engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root@127.0.0.1/music_marketing?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0', pool_recycle=3600)

        # create a configured "Session" class
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine)

        # create a Session
        session = Session()

        thelist_id = item.get('entity_id')

        for email in item.get('emails'):
            if not email in self.seen:
                self.seen.append(email)
                try:
                    ins = data.insert().values(thelist=thelist_id, tag=22, value=email)
                except Exception, e:
                    print 'INSERT ERROR: ', thelist_id

        return item
```

Questions:

How do I pass a command line argument to be used by the FuriousmePipeline, e.g., the "thelist_id" is the row ID from the database, the scraped data should be written back to the database using this as the value for the foreign key column so it ties back to the original entity.

Comment: What isn't working, or what is your problem?  Looking at this, you're already passing `thelist_id` to your pipeline via `item['entity_id']`.

Comment: You're right! the issue is in items I defined it as "thelist_id" and in pipelines I'm getting "entity_id" !! This solves the main problem. Now it's not writing to the database, but hopefully I can figure that out. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to @LearnAWK and @Rejected for helping me figure this out.

To store an argument, set up a item to hold it in items.py

```
import scrapy

class FuriousmeItem(scrapy.Item):
    emails = scrapy.Field()
    entity_id = scrapy.Field()  # this will hold the argument
```

Setup the spider to receive the arguments in the `def __init__' as below. Then actually store the item via the`def parse_dir_contents` as below.

furious.py (the spider)

```
import scrapy
from furiousme.items import FuriousmeItem


class FuriousSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "furious"

    def __init__(self, domain, start_url, thelist_id):
        self.allowed_domains = [domain]
        self.start_urls = [start_url]
        self.thelist_id = thelist_id  # this receives the argument


    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css("a::attr('href')"):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath("//body//a"):
            item = FuriousmeItem()
            item['emails'] = response.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]/text()").extract()
            item['entity_id'] = self.thelist_id # this stores the argument
            yield item
```

The settings.py needs to call the pipeline

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'furiousme'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['furiousme.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'furiousme.spiders'

ITEM_PIPELINES = [
    'furiousme.pipelines.FuriousmePipeline',
]
```

pipelines.py

```
import logging
import sys

# DATABASE
import pymysql
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.sql import table, column, exists
from sqlalchemy import *

sys.path.append("/Volumes/Orange-1a/^datamine/^scripts/^foundation/")
import music_tables
from music_tables import *

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class FuriousmePipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.seen = []

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        logger.info(item)

        some_engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root@127.0.0.1/music_marketing?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0', pool_recycle=3600)

        # create a configured "Session" class
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine)

        # create a Session
        session = Session()

        thelist_id = item.get('entity_id')

        for email in item.get('emails'):
            if not email in self.seen:
                self.seen.append(email)
                try:
                    ins = data.insert().values(thelist=thelist_id, tag=22, value=email)
                    conn.execute(ins)  # remember this to write to database!
                except Exception, e:
                    print 'INSERT ERROR: ', thelist_id

        return item
```

Result:
This will write the data, de-duplicated, into a database!

Answer (score 0):

Your frustration is totally understandable.  This [example](https://github.com/rolando/dirbot-mysql) about Scrapy and MySQL on Github has given me tremendous help.  It contains all the codes you need to write to MySQL database.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good start. I'm still stuck on the part of passing the command line argument for the database row id to scrapy for use with the pipelines.py class that does the writing.

Comment: Why and do you really need to use command line arguments to provide database row id?  Those can be handled in pipeline file.  My understanding is that you try to using scrapy to scrape some email addresses and write the unique ones to a MySQL database.  Are there anything I missed?

Comment: I have a database with 2 tables: thelist and data. The thelist table is a list of entities - venues, blogs, businesses. I have scraped data for these already through other sites (mostly directories) and put that info into the data table, which is related by a foreign key to thelist via thelist_id (id of the entity's row in thelist table). I want scrapy as another layer of scraping, e.g., it pulls info from the thelist including the row id, then writes to the data table, so it relates back to the entity in thelist. Hope that makes sense!